# nvd3 x-axis shorter than graph

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, axis, nvd3.js

I used NVD3 to make a horizontal bar chart. My largest entry in the data is 62. The last value on the X-axis therefore is 62. The chart, however, reaches to somewhere around 70. I would like to extend the x-axis to 70, displaying 70 as the last value on it.
[image]

This is my code for now. I have tried to add a domain suggested in other posts, but I have experienced that to work only for an Y-axis

```
var color1 = ["#ffff7b"]

    d3.dsv(";")("data/per-soort_draaitabel.csv", 
    function(d){
        return {
            label:d["onderwerp"],value:parseInt(d.totaal)
        };
    },

    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var numbers = [{
            key: "doodsoorzaken"
            , values: data
        }];
        nv.addGraph(function() {
            var chart3 = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart()
                .x(function(d) { return d.label })
                .y(function(d) { return d.value })
                .margin({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 175})
                .showValues(true)
                .color(color1)
                .showControls(false)
                .valueFormat(function(d){return d.toFixed(0);});
            console.log(data);

            chart3.yAxis
                .tickFormat(d3.format(',.0f'));

            d3.select('#chart3')
                .datum(numbers)
                .call(chart3);

            nv.utils.windowResize(chart3.update);

            return chart3;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope anyone can be of help!

Comment: `chart3.xDomain([0, 70])`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but when I do this, all bars become one and on the y-Axis I see the numbers 70 and 0. When I changed  `xDomain` to `yDomain`, the last number of the graph was indeed 70, but I still had the horizontal lines run out of the graph.

Comment: have you tried using `chart3.y( function (d){ return d.y < 70 ? d.y : 70;})` ?